# Rank n types, interfaces, and unification idiris

Tags: polymorphism, idris, rank-n-types

In Idris, this works:

```
appShow : Show a => ({b : _} -> Show b => b -> String) -> a -> String
appShow s x = s x

tAppShow : String
tAppShow = appShow show 5
```

However, a somewhat different version doesn't. This compiles:

```
specializeMonad : ({m : _} -> Monad m => m Int) -> IO Int
specializeMonad f = f
```

But if I try to use it:

```
tSpecializeMonad1 : IO Int
tSpecializeMonad1 = specializeMonad (return 5)

-- Or trying harder to keep it polymorphic
tSpecializeMonad2 : IO Int
tSpecializeMonad2 = specializeMonad (the ({m : _} -> Monad m => m Int) (return 5))
```

Then I get `Can't find implementation for Monad m` for the first and:

```
                Type mismatch between
                        m Integer (Type of return 5)
                and
                        m2 Int (Expected type)
```

For the second.

I noticed this happens even just with `return 5`. Eg, if I try in the repl:

```
> return 5
Can't find implementation for Monad m
```

Is there a way to have a value with a type that's interface-polymorphic? Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the principles behind Idris' typechecking? (I'm coming from Haskell, as might already be obvious.)